# "DSO missing from command line" when using -nostdlib (g++)

Tags: c++, g++, ld

This may be a bit of a weird request but I'm trying to compile some software with g++ with the `-nostdlib` flag.

I'm pretty new to c++ and I'm still learning how linking and compiling works but I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include "../lib/gamesys/types.h"


int main() {
    types::setUid(1001);
}
```

Using these commands:
`g++ -Wall -g -c bin/scripttwo.cpp -o bin/scripttwo.o -std=c++14`
and
`g++ -o bin/scripttwo bin/scripttwo.o software/*.o hardware/*.o *.o -nostdlib -Llib/lib/ -ltypes -ljsoncpp -lreadline -ltypes`

and I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: software/FS.o: undefined reference to symbol '_Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the stdlib because once I remove `-nostdlib`, it compiles and links fine.

How can I solve this (it is pretty important that I don't include stdlibs)

Note: If you want to know why I'm trying to avoid stdlibs, let me know, its a long a convoluted story lol

Comment: You need to recompile **all** your C++ code with `-fno-exceptions` and `-fno-rtti` flags. This includes all third-party libraries. You also may need to rewrite `libjsoncpp` because it seems to use the standard library. Good luck.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I assumed that once a library is compiled, it doesn't matter if it don't include its dependencies. For example. If i have library1.o and it depends on library2.o, if i link them together into library3.so, i don't need to link with library1 and library2 in my binary. Is this correct? @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: Correcting you. Objects are one thing, and shared libraries are quite a different thing. A shared library may depend on other shared libraries, The error "DSO missing from command line" means precisely that: one of your shared libraries depends on another shared library, and you are not linking against that dependency. `libjsoncpp` supplied with your linux distro uses the standard library and depends on it.